# When to close a cursor in MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a program which runs a loop and every iteration runs a sql query. I currently have it implemented as.

```
mysql_connection = MySQLdb.connect(...)
for record in records:
  cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()
  curson.execute(some_query)
  result = None
  for r in cursor:
       result = r
  cursor.close()
  #Do something with result
mysql_connection.close()
```

This is taking a lot of time as everytime the loop runs, a new cursor is created. Is placing the cursor outside the loop a better approach or I can use something else to increase the performance.

I have the search query already on indexed column thus scope of improvement at mysql side is less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to create cursor one time. Also pay attention that you do `return` in cycle, so it seems that you call `cursor.execute` only one time.

Comment: Are their any particular issues faced due to using the same cursor again and again?

Comment: No, cursors are used only to store results, so you can use it again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `c.arraysize` to a value that makes sense for your use case (where `c` is the cursor), and stick the cursor outside of the loop. See this page: http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#cursor-objects

> If you wanted more rows, you could use c.fetchmany(n) or c.fetchall(). These do exactly what you think they do. On c.fetchmany(n), the n is optional and defaults to c.arraysize, which is normally 1. Both of these methods return a sequence of rows, or an empty sequence if there are no more rows. If you use a weird cursor class, the rows themselves might not be tuples.